# Ajax error выбивает мне

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Не могу найти ошибку при ajax запросе , уже все перепробовал, ошибку выбивает мне хоть ответ приходит 200 ок `res.write('hello');`
Ajax запрос:

```js
$('#next').click(function(){
            var msg   = $('#form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/user/confirm_password',
                dataType: "json",
                data: msg,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error:  function(xhr,textStatus,err){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
```

Все данные успешно приходят на сервер и обрабатываются не пойму откуда ошибка, буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: А куда приходит ответ, в `success` или `error`?

Comment: в error, а нужно в success

Comment: вот больше кода `transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.log('Send: ' + info.response);
                res.write('hello');
            }
        });`  console.log('Send: ' + info.response); -
выводит send + info.response

Comment: ответ кодируете в `json`?

Comment: нет просто отправляю res.write('hello');

Comment: конкретно вот здесь `http://localhost:3000/user/confirm_password` чем обрабатывается запрос? `javascript`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35520/discussion-between-zejur-and-vasyok).

Comment: оброботчиком `this.confirmPassword = function(req, res, next){

        ...
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.log('Send: ' + info.response);
                res.write('hello');
            }
        });

    };`

Comment: По идеи мне должно прийти в data - hello (success response)

Comment: А что вообще приходит в ответ?

Comment: alert('error');

Comment: Проверьте настройки сервера, и посмотрите что пишет в консоли, вы же для чего-то консоль лог прописывали? ))), но посмотреть в консоли нужно что именно происходит с самим запросом, это должно быть достаточно хорошо видно в FireBug`e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну если пошла речь о том, что у нас проблема в node.js, то лучше слать JSON правильно:

```
exports.confirm_password = function(request, response) {
   response.json({text: 'hello'});
}
```

а не писать костыль по правке JSON.stringify() и отправлять данные как текст, а не как JSON.

и тогда не нужно ставить (менять на) `dataType: "text"`

Answer (score 3):

Ваше 'hello' не парсится как ожидаемый json. Поставьте `dataType: "text",`.

Comment: я уже поменял ))

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/user/confirm_password',
    dataType: "json",
    data: msg
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(errorData){
    console.log(errorData);
});
```

Это не решение, но как минимум будет видно, что происходит в консоли, замените свой запрос на этот.

Comment: Ситуация следующая, когда я отправляю ajax post запрос , то оно в консоль выводит буквально на 1 сек , а затем перетирает , видно что там объект

Comment: $('#next') - кнопка формы, с которой вы пытаетесь отправить запрос, <button> или <input type="submit">?

Comment: все уже есть ответ : res.send(JSON.stringify({"text": "hello"})); 
Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Vasyok Ответ который Вам предложили не правильный, точнее костыльный, смотрите тот ответ что дал я res.json({});

Answer (score -1):

Поскольку просто строка не парсится в json , то нужно просто подделать

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({"text": "hello"}));
```

Comment: Данный пример не очень корректен, т.к. это больше костыль нежели правильный ответ. res.json({}) для этого существует.